Why are Lebanese fleeing to Syria, or more precisely, which areas of Syria are they fleeing to?
It's not like there's no Hezbollah in Syria, or that Israel is not striking Hezbollah (and the IRGC) there too.
So, why are Lebanese fleeing to Syria? Are there some areas of Syria that are somehow perceived as more safe than Lebanon? Or are they ultimately going to Turkey, possibly Europe, etc.?
And are they even mostly Lebanese, those who cross to Syria now? E.g. back in May there were 1.5 million Syrians in Lebanon, probably most of them fleeing the civil war.

UN claimed about a week ago that 100,000 crossed into Syria. MEE says today that 176,000 Syrians have done so, which would entail most are Syrians?


It's not like there's no Hezbollah in Syria

People are not fleeing Hezbollah.

or that Israel is not striking Hezbollah (and the IRGC) there too.

Actually, Israel is carrying out very few strikes in Syria - as far as I can tell (liveuamap.com ; look at the Oct 3 2024 data if you're following the link later on). They have, however, decided to attack the main road people are using to go from Lebanon and Syria.


So, why are Lebanese fleeing to Syria?

So that they don't get bombed; the airstrikes have been very intense, even according as reported by US media (cnn.com).
Also, some likely flee so they don't get killed by the Israeli ground incursion if that unfolds further, and any cross-fire in their villages and towns of residence.
Syria is in a bad state since the war, with the horrible sanctions and everything, but like I wrote above - relatively safer that Lebanon.
Note that the Israeli military has been specifically threatening Lebanese living and the South to evacuate their towns lest they too be bombed - and that's not some thin strip, but well past the Litani river. And we know the Israeli military has no qualms about massive civilian casualties, so people need to go somewhere. And if it's too close - it's still possible they'll get bombed, like the Gazans who run around from one place to another only to be hit by Israel again. So it's "safe haven lottery", with the prize being your life.

back in May there were 1.5 million Syrians in Lebanon, probably most of them fleeing the civil war.

I would guess that a decent-to-large fraction of the people crossing over to Syria, are from Syria, and have decided to go back. Also note that the civil war is kind-of-over in most of Syria. It only simmers on in the Idlib region, and mostly around its edges.

I'm pretty sure that these figures are preliminary and likely to change in upcoming days, but for now (4 October 2024) the UNHRC says that of the 185,000 that crossed into Syria from Lebanon recently, 70% are Syrians and 30% Lebanese.

A total of 185,000 people are estimated to
have crossed from Lebanon to Syria since the
escalation of hostilities in Lebanon. It is
estimated that around 70 per cent are Syrians
and 30 per cent are Lebanese nationals.

Their destinations (esp. of the Lebanese) are not always clear. An earlier report (Oct 1) said that Syria opened a few reception centres, but these don't seem to amount to much more than a couple of thousand places/persons. The Syrians are said (in some related report) to be mostly trying to rejoin their relatives.
